# Grid not rendering in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, editablegrid

I am working with [EditableGrid](http://www.editablegrid.net/en) to generate and manipulate column models dynamically. Everything has gone according to the plan, except for just one compatibility issue with Firefox (..yes not IE -_-). I understand this is some sort of Closure issue maybe? I cannot seem to work a way around this. This is where something goes wrong:

```
EditableGrid.prototype.initializeGrid = function () {
    with (this) {
        //apply cell validators and inforenderers in headers
        var regex = [];
        for (var count = 0; count < selectedColumnNames.length; ++count) {
            var columnObj = findSelectedColumnObject(selectedColumnNames[count]);

            //check if regex is provided
            if (!(columnObj[0].validationRegex == "")) {
                // add a cell validator
                var expression = new RegExp(columnObj[0].validationRegex);
                regex[columnObj[0].name] = new RegExp(columnObj[0].validationRegex);
                var valObj = GetValidatorObject(expression);
                addCellValidator(columnObj[0].name, valObj);
            }
        }

        function GetValidatorObject(regObj){
            var obj = {
                isValid: function (value) {
                    return value == "" || (regObj.test(value));
                }
            };
            return new CellValidator(obj);
        }
}
```

The exception it throws is:

> ReferenceError: GetValidatorObject is not defined [var valObj =
>   GetValidatorObject(expression);]

Any ideas?

Comment: Nitpick, avoid `with`! You are just going to create major headaches by using it. And my guess is that is the reason for you error.

Comment: I do not get it, why FF? It works perfectly with other browsers?

Comment: it works when I moved `GetValidatorObject` out of the scope of `with(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `epascarello`, the work around was simple, I moved the method of `GetValidatorObject` out of the scope of `with (this)`. Now it works with FF. When I further digged into the matter, I found [avoid using 'with' keyword in JS](http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/05/avoid-javascripts-with-keyword/) really interesting. This might clear grey areas.